# Kusto: Do a leftsemi join including columns from right table

Tags: join, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics

I want to lookup values from a different query. I stumpled upon two keywords which may could make sense: `join` and `lookup`.
`leftsemi` join looks exactly what I need, but I cannot access columns on the right side.
Any other variants that I've tried are adding more rows. The resulting table should not have more entries than `FactTable`, but can be less in case of null values.

```
let FactTable=datatable(name:string,timeprofile:string) [
  "Paul", "10:30",
  "Eric", "8:30",
  "Eric", "9:30",
  "Petra", "9:49"
];
let DimTable=datatable(name:string,details:string) [
   "Paul", "+",
   "Eric", "-",
   "Eric", "-",
   "Eric", "-",
   "Lessly", "++",
   "Martha", "+",
   "Martha", "+",
   "Martha", "+"
];
FactTable
| join kind=leftsemi DimTable on name
```

But the resulting table is missing `details` column from `DimTable`.
[image]

Comment: Dim tale should not hold duplicates keys

Comment: [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Performance wise it's recommended to [Join when left side is small and right side is large](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42QsQ6CQAyGd56iuUkjJhgdBMOmTpowuBmHClWrx6F3x2Diw8thEI0JMV3ab/j7tZIsLDG1G9xLijO0VVVdT2FOkbGa1dG3nNNVFweWDerD1gMQCZZS%20CBGQTQOhO/QQnPq0PSHhG%20SkNX4QpNQeLuZJyuLOeddEhlZZGm%20BFqDQZ3cLhv%20Oa/IGHmvE5qINWp7ws/QbuL8G3fvAeeCFVxYZTErRbpUfCupfTEUCtxZT2cDAkJ4AQAA)
2. Once you switch the order of the tables, the default Join kind, [innerunique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#default-join-flavor), does exactly what you need - inner join with duplicates removal from the left side

---

```
DimTable
| join kind=innerunique FactTable on name
```

or simply

```
DimTable
| join FactTable on name
```

| name | details | name1 | timeprofile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | + | Paul | 10:30 |
| Eric | - | Eric | 8:30 |
| Eric | - | Eric | 9:30 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42QsQ6CQAyGd56iuUkjJhgdBMOmTpowuBmHClWrx6F3x2Diw8thEI0JMV3ab/j7tZIsLDG1G9xLijO0VVVdT2FOkbGa1dG3nNNVFweWDerD1gMQCZZS%20CBGQTQOhO/QQnPq0PSHhG%20SkNX4QpNQeLuZJyuLOeddEhlZZGm%20BFqDQZ3cLhv%20Oa/IGHmvE5qINWp7ws/QbuL8G3fvAeeCFVxYZTErRbpUfCupfTEUCtxZT2cDAkJ4AQAA)

Comment: I never considered switching the right side to left side. Plus: I have missing data which leaded to false conclusions about innerunique. Anyway, thank you :-)